# Coerce type without creating temporary variable

Tags: java, generics, types, casting, vavr

I have the following function:

```
  <K, P, Q> Map<K, List<Q>> convert(Map<K, ? extends List<? extends P>> input) {
    return HashMap.empty();
  }
```

I am calling it in the following way:

```
Map<Integer, List<? extends String>> stringMap = HashMap.empty();
Map<Integer, List<? extends Double>> doubleMap = HashMap.empty();
Map<Integer, List<Boolean>> stringMapConverted = convert(stringMap);
Map<Integer, List<Boolean>> merged = stringMapConverted.merge(convert(doubleMap));
```

However, I want to do this without having to create a temporary variable first.
Something like this:

```
Map<Integer, List<? extends String>> stringMap = HashMap.empty();
Map<Integer, List<? extends Double>> doubleMap = HashMap.empty();
Map<Integer, List<Boolean>> merged = convert(stringMap).merge(convert(doubleMap));
```

However, I am getting a compilation error here:

```
'merge(io.vavr.collection.Map<? extends java.lang.Integer,? extends io.vavr.collection.List<java.lang.Object>>)' in 'io.vavr.collection.Map' cannot be applied to '(io.vavr.collection.Map<java.lang.Integer,io.vavr.collection.List<? extends java.lang.Double>>)'

Required type: Map<? extends Integer,? extends List<Object>>
Provided: Map<Integer,List<? extends Double>>
```

I also tried casting explicitly:

```
Map<Integer, List<Boolean>> merged2 = ((Map<Integer,List<Boolean>>)convert(stringMap)).merge(doubleMap);
```

but its throwing a compilation error:

```
Inconvertible types; cannot cast 'io.vavr.collection.Map<java.lang.Integer,io.vavr.collection.List<java.lang.Object>>' to 'io.vavr.collection.Map<java.lang.Integer,io.vavr.collection.List<java.lang.Boolean>>'
```

The signature of `Map.merge()` is as follows:

```
Map<K, V> merge(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> that);
```

The Map and List classes are from [vavr](https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr).

Comment: Maybe use type witness `Map<Integer, List<Boolean>> merged = this.<Integer, String, Boolean>convert(stringMap).merge(convert(doubleMap));`

Comment: @samabcde Thanks it worked. Feel free to add it as an answer so that I can accept and close the question.

Comment: How would your convert method figure out the type argument `Q` if you don't provide any  input to that method that has anything to do with `Q`, which could be used to produce the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [type witness](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html), or so called [`TypeArguments` mentioned in 15.12 in SE11 JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12) to specify the type argument when invoking `convert`.

> MethodInvocation:
>   MethodName ( [ArgumentList] )
>   TypeName . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
>   ExpressionName . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
>   Primary . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
>   super . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
>   TypeName . super . [TypeArguments] Identifier ( [ArgumentList] )
> ArgumentList: Expression {, Expression}

Note that we cannot omit the instance name->(this) when using `TypeArguments`.

```
Map<Integer, List<Boolean>> merged = this.<Integer, String, Boolean>convert(stringMap).merge(convert(doubleMap));
```